# How do i send notification from Springboot using Firebase In App Messaging?

Tags: firebase, spring-boot, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

I want to send notification from Spring boot using firebase In App Messaging. I have done using firebase cloud messaging but get difficulties in firebase In App Messaging.

please provide some source or other suggestions like Spring boot builder() methods or other method to di this.

Answer (score 0):

The firebase is supported send a notification with HTTP protocol, You can use RestTemplate call HTTP request to FirestBase server (Refer: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1). Or use the API firebase for java https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#java